# How to filter the output from the output of this powershell command?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Microsoft-Windows-PrintService/Operational";} |
Format-Table -Property TimeCreated,
                        @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
                        @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
                        @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
                        @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
                        @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}}
```

I want to filter out all those lines where PrinterName is "MyPrinter" from the output of the above command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a `Where-Object` condition before you format the table:

```
Get-WinEvent -FilterHashTable @{LogName="Security";} | 
    Where-Object { $_.properties[4].value -eq 'MyPrinter'} | 
    Format-Table -Property TimeCreated,
        @{label='UserName';expression={$_.properties[2].value}},
        @{label='ComputerName';expression={$_.properties[3].value}},
        @{label='PrinterName';expression={$_.properties[4].value}},
        @{label='PrintSize';expression={$_.properties[6].value}},
        @{label='Pages';expression={$_.properties[7].value}}
```

Comment: I think you want `$_.properties[4].value -ne 'MyPrinter'`

Comment: @AdminOfThings You might be right. munish just adopt the operator to your need.